# Apply a function to a column inside a structure of a Spark DataFrame, replacing that column

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I cannot find exactly what I am looking for, so here it is my question. I fetch from MongoDb some data into a Spark Dataframe. The dataframe has the following schema (`df.printSchema`):

```
|-- flight: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- legs: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- arrival: timestamp (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- departure: timestamp (nullable = true)
|    |-- segments: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- arrival: timestamp (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- departure: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Do note the top-level structure, followed by an array, inside which I need to change my data.
For example:

```js
{
  "flight": {
    "legs": [{
        "departure": ISODate("2020-10-30T13:35:00.000Z"),
        "arrival": ISODate("2020-10-30T14:47:00.000Z")
      }
    ],
    "segments": [{
        "departure": ISODate("2020-10-30T13:35:00.000Z"),
        "arrival": ISODate("2020-10-30T14:47:00.000Z")
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to export this in Json, but for some business reason, I want the arrival dates to have a different format than the departure dates. For example, I may want to export the departure ISODate in ms from epoch, but not the arrival one.

To do so, I thought of applying a custom function to do the transformation:

```scala
  // Here I can do any tranformation. I hope to replace the timestamp with the needed value
  val doSomething: UserDefinedFunction = udf(  (value: Seq[Timestamp]) => {
    value.map(x => "doSomething" + x.getTime) }
  )

  val newDf = df.withColumn("flight.legs.departure",
    doSomething(df.col("flight.legs.departure")))
```

But this simply returns a brand new column, containing an array of a single `doSomething` string.

```js
{
  "flight": {
    "legs": [{
        "arrival": "2020-10-30T14:47:00Z",
        "departure": "2020-10-30T13:35:00Z"
      }
    ],
    "segments": [{
        "arrival": "2020-10-30T14:47:00Z",
        "departure": "2020-10-30T13:35:00Z",
      }
    ]
  },
  "flight.legs.departure": ["doSomething1596268800000"]
}
```

And `newDf.show(1)`

```
+--------------------+---------------------+
|              flight|flight.legs.departure|
+--------------------+---------------------+
|[[[182], 94, [202...| [doSomething15962...|
+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Instead of

```js
{
  ...
        "arrival": "2020-10-30T14:47:00Z",
        //leg departure date that I changed
        "departure": "doSomething1596268800000"
  ...   // segments not affected in this example
        "arrival": "2020-10-30T14:47:00Z",
        "departure": "2020-10-30T13:35:00Z",
 ...
}
```

Any ideas how to proceed?

**Edit - clarification**: 
Please bear in mind that my schema is way more complex than what shown above. For example, there is yet another top level `data` tag, so `flight` is below along with other information. Then inside `flight`, `legs` and `segments` there are multiple more elements, some that are also nested. I only focused on the ones that I needed to change.

I am saying this, because I would like the simplest solution that would scale. I.e. ideally one that would simply change the required elements without having to de-construct and that re-construct the whole nested structure. If we cannot avoid that, is using case classes the simplest solution?

Comment: withColumn will always give you new column, instead of withColumn can you use select & try ?

Comment: To my understanding, select will just select that. I need to keep the rest of the json.

Comment: It seems that I have to define the respective case class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733640/how-to-modify-a-spark-dataframe-with-a-complex-nested-structure
I will try that solution.

Comment: You can do it using selects with structs, arrays etc, see ans.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code below.

Execution Time

`With UDF`     : Time taken: 679 ms

`Without UDF`  : Time taken: 1493 ms

`Code With UDF`

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  // Creating UDF to update value inside array.
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
  val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss") // For me departure values are in string, so using this to convert sql timestmap.
  val doSomething = udf((value: Seq[String]) => {
     value.map(x => s"dosomething${dateFormat.parse(x).getTime}")
  })

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
dateFormat: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@41bd83a
doSomething: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(StringType,true),Some(List(ArrayType(StringType,true))))


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

spark.time {
val updated = df.select("flight.*").withColumn("legs",arrays_zip($"legs.arrival",doSomething($"legs.departure")).cast("array<struct<arrival:string,departure:string>>")).select(struct($"segments",$"legs").as("flight"))
updated.printSchema
updated.show(false)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

root
 |-- flight: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- segments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arrival: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- departure: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- legs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arrival: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- departure: string (nullable = true)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|flight                                                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[2020-10-30T14:47:00, 2020-10-30T13:35:00]], [[2020-10-30T14:47:00, dosomething1604045100000]]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Time taken: 679 ms

scala>
```

`Code Without UDF`

```
scala> val df = spark.read.json(Seq("""{"flight": {"legs": [{"departure": "2020-10-30T13:35:00","arrival": "2020-10-30T14:47:00"}],"segments": [{"departure": "2020-10-30T13:35:00","arrival": "2020-10-30T14:47:00"}]}}""").toDS)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [flight: struct<legs: array<struct<arrival:string,departure:string>>, segments: array<struct<arrival:string,departure:string>>>]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- flight: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- legs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arrival: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- departure: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- segments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arrival: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- departure: string (nullable = true)


scala> df.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|flight                                                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[2020-10-30T14:47:00, 2020-10-30T13:35:00]], [[2020-10-30T14:47:00, 2020-10-30T13:35:00]]]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

spark.time {
val updated= df
            .select("flight.*")
            .select($"segments",$"legs.arrival",$"legs.departure") // extracting legs struct column values.
            .withColumn("departure",explode($"departure")) // exploding departure column
            .withColumn("departure",concat_ws("-",lit("something"),$"departure".cast("timestamp").cast("long"))) // updating departure column values
            .groupBy($"segments",$"arrival") // grouping columns except legs column
            .agg(collect_list($"departure").as("departure")) // constructing list back
            .select($"segments",arrays_zip($"arrival",$"departure").as("legs")) // construction arrival & departure columns using arrays_zip method.
            .select(struct($"legs",$"segments").as("flight")) // finally creating flight by combining legs & segments columns.

  updated.printSchema
  updated.show(false)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

root
 |-- flight: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- legs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- arrival: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- departure: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- segments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arrival: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- departure: string (nullable = true)

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|flight                                                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[2020-10-30T14:47:00, something-1604045100]], [[2020-10-30T14:47:00, 2020-10-30T13:35:00]]]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Time taken: 1493 ms

scala>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. How can get the $ symbol? Because for me I always have to do ``df.col("..")``.

Comment: You have to import spark.implicits._ to get that symbol

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I have added a clarification concerning the size / complexity of my schema. Do I need to reconstruct my schema in both of your proposals?

Comment: In both cases you have to reconstruct schema back to original after updating values, If you have complex schema try to use UDF otherwise without UDF.

Comment: Is it possible to post your complete schema ?

Comment: If you see above answer I am extracting only required columns other columns are not touching just using names because we need those columns in final DF.

Comment: I cannot post the whole schema online (intellecutal property of my company). Indeed the second solution seemed way more complex. I can check what I can post tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|flight                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[2020-10-30T13:35:00.000Z, 2020-10-30T14:47:00.000Z]], [[2020-10-30T13:35:00.000Z, 2020-10-30T14:47:00.000Z]]]|
|[[[2020-10-25T13:15:00.000Z, 2020-10-25T14:37:00.000Z]], [[2020-10-25T13:15:00.000Z, 2020-10-25T14:37:00.000Z]]]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


scala> 

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- flight: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- legs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dep: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- segments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dep: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arr: string (nullable = true)


scala> 

scala> val myudf = udf(
     |   (arrs:Seq[String]) => {
     |     arrs.map("something" ++ _)
     |   } 
     | )
myudf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(StringType,true),Some(List(ArrayType(StringType,true))))

scala> val df2 = df.select($"flight", myudf($"flight.legs.arr") as "editedArrs")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [flight: struct<legs: array<struct<dep:string,arr:string>>, segments: array<struct<dep:string,arr:string>>>, editedArrs: array<string>]

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- flight: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- legs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dep: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- segments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dep: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arr: string (nullable = true)
 |-- editedArrs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)


scala> df2.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|flight                                                                                                          |editedArrs                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|[[[2020-10-30T13:35:00.000Z, 2020-10-30T14:47:00.000Z]], [[2020-10-30T13:35:00.000Z, 2020-10-30T14:47:00.000Z]]]|[something2020-10-30T14:47:00.000Z]|
|[[[2020-10-25T13:15:00.000Z, 2020-10-25T14:37:00.000Z]], [[2020-10-25T13:15:00.000Z, 2020-10-25T14:37:00.000Z]]]|[something2020-10-25T14:37:00.000Z]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+


scala> 

scala> 

scala> val df3 = df2.select(struct(arrays_zip($"flight.legs.dep", $"editedArrs") cast "array<struct<dep:string,arr:string>>" as "legs", $"flight.segments") as "flight")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [flight: struct<legs: array<struct<dep:string,arr:string>>, segments: array<struct<dep:string,arr:string>>>]

scala> 

scala> df3.printSchema
root
 |-- flight: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- legs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dep: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- segments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dep: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- arr: string (nullable = true)


scala> 

scala> df3.show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|flight                                                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[2020-10-30T13:35:00.000Z, something2020-10-30T14:47:00.000Z]], [[2020-10-30T13:35:00.000Z, 2020-10-30T14:47:00.000Z]]]|
|[[[2020-10-25T13:15:00.000Z, something2020-10-25T14:37:00.000Z]], [[2020-10-25T13:15:00.000Z, 2020-10-25T14:37:00.000Z]]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. If I understand correctly, your solution is applicable even though I may have a way larger schema than the one presentation (see edit in the question). What I mean, is that I don't need to manually reconstruct the whole structure.

Comment: I don't see why you cannot.